# JavaScript Callback being kept in memory and excuted with new callback

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events, notifyjs

I'm working on a CMS type project using ajax. My problem occurs with the notify.js javascript library located here https://notifyjs.com/.

With my local copy I realized that I can create confirm buttons sleekly designed without using Javascript's built in `alert()` or `confirm()` methods and make it look like this:

[image: photo].

Seeing that the source code provided no way to explicitly add callbacks from outside the library I modified it to my will, where the "callback" parameter is my custom parameter

I.E.

```
    //confirmation notification
    Notification.prototype.confirm = function (style, position, title, text, callback) {
        var icon = "fa fa-adjust";
        if (style == "error") {
            icon = "fa fa-exclamation";
        } else if (style == "warning") {
            icon = "fa fa-warning";
        } else if (style == "success") {
            icon = "fa fa-check";
        } else if (style == "info") {
            icon = "fa fa-question";
        } else {
            icon = "fa fa-adjust";
        }
        $.notify({
            title: title,
            text : text + '<div class="clearfix"></div><br><a id="yesConfirmBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-default yes">Yes</a><a id="noConfirmBtn"  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger no">No</a>',
            image: "<i class='" + icon + "'></i>"
        }, {
            style         : 'metro',
            className     : style,
            globalPosition: position,
            showAnimation : "show",
            showDuration  : 0,
            hideDuration  : 0,
            autoHide      : false,
            clickToHide   : false
        });
        //listen for click events from this style
        $(document).on('click', '.notifyjs-metro-base .no', function () {
            // turn off event listener on yes click
            $(document).off("click", '.notifyjs-metro-base .yes');

            //programmatically trigger propogating hide event
            $(this).trigger('notify-hide');
        });
        var yesClick = function () {
            //callback when user clicks
            callback();
            // callback is assigned empty closure  because on
            // the next confirm request this callback and
            // the new one will be called
            callback = function(){

            };

            //hide notification
            $(this).trigger('notify-hide');

        };
        $(document).on('click', '.notifyjs-metro-base .yes', yesClick);
    }
```

In the click listeners my problem occurs the `yesClick` listener mainly as it continue to add the callbacks one on top the other so each time a callback is created and triggered the old one is triggered then the rest till the newest callback.

To by pass this problem I made the callback point to a empty anonymous function so when the old one's are executed it wouldn't do anything but this way still doesn't solve my problem as the callbacks will still be in memory.

The callback passed in performs an Ajax request to delete a row in the database.

This is what the callback looks like

```
var self = this;
// triggers notify.js confirmDelete() method passing in the 
// body, title, and callback
this.notif.confirmDelete("Are you sure?", "Delete this Item?", function () {
    // creates a notification to show user their 
    // transaction is being processed
    self.notif.info("Deleting");
    // callback for if the ajax request was successful
    var successCB = function (text) {
        if (text.indexOf("true") !== -1) {
            self.notif.success("Item has been deleted", "Successfully Deleted");
            var form  = new Validate(),
                table = new Table();
            form.resetForm();
            table.removeRow(data.id);
        } else {
            self.notif.error("Could not be deleted...");
        }
      // callback if ajax request failed
    }, failCB     = function () {
        // this key word refer's to a method called 
        //Success which is the same as  successCB as they
        //are placed in the same object literal
        this.Success("false");
    };
    self.ajaxRequest(successCB, failCB, data);
});
```

`self.ajaxRequest` looks like this (this is a custom ajax library I made if it seems strange)

```
 var self          = this;
var dataToProcess = data || {};
// basic set up for ajax request
Ajaxify({
    host        : self.hostName + "Backend/manage/" + self.processFile,
    data        : [dataToProcess],
    responseType: "text",
    method      : "POST",
    execute     : true,// executes request right away
    Success     : successCallback,
    Failure     : failureCallback
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I solve this?

What is the cause of it?

(Note: if any further info is needed let me know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove click events with off, because you're adding global click with on

```
   function noClick() {
        //programmatically trigger propogating hide event
        $(this).trigger('notify-hide');
        removeEvents();
   }
   function removeEvents() {
       $(document).off('click', '.notifyjs-metro-base .no', noClick);
       $(document).off('click', '.notifyjs-metro-base .yes', yesClick);
   }
   $(document).on('click', '.notifyjs-metro-base .no', no);
   function yesClick () {
        //callback when user clicks
        callback();

        //hide notification
        $(this).trigger('notify-hide');
        removeEvents();
    };
    $(document).on('click', '.notifyjs-metro-base .yes', yesClick);
```

Comment: Excellent thank you, I have no prior experience with JQuery so I totally overlooked the "on" method. Thanks!